# Fade In and Fade out in Animation Swift

Tags: ios, animation, swift, fadein, fadeout

I have an UIImageView with an Animation and, in the UIView, I apply a fadeIn effect, but I need to apply fade out when the UIImageView, which is animated, when is touched.

This is what I make to fade in.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: delay, 
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        uiImageView.alpha = 1.0
        }
```

Comment: Is your problem that you can't get the image view to fade out if you trigger it during the fade in animation?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is what I would do based on my research: (Supposing you're using storyboard)

1. Go to your UIImageView, and under the Attributes, check the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox.
2. Drag a TapGestureRecognizer on top of the image view.
3. Control click on the Tap Gesture and drag to make a action on your ViewControler.swift.
4. Add the following code inside:

   ```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
       self.uiImageView.alpha = 0.0
   }, completion: nil)
   ```

Then you're done!

Comment: What value I need in delay?

Comment: @PlugInBoy I edited the block of code in my answer. That should work fine.

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4 . Add fade in and fade out function to UIView object**

```
extension UIView {

    func fadeIn(_ duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: completion)  }

    func fadeOut(_ duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 1.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.3
    }, completion: completion)
   }
}
```

**Example**

```
label.fadeIn()

label.fadeOut()

imageView.fadeOut(completion: {
    (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
})

label.fadeIn(completion: {
    (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    label.text = "Changed!"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  UIViewAnimationOptions is now UIView.Animation Options

Answer (score 12):

Starting from iOS 10 Apple launched new [iOS Animations SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimating) that is much more powerful, especially concerning timings functions and interactivity.

Fade out code with this approach will:

```
UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
    self.uiImageView.alpha = 0.0
}).startAnimation()
```

To get more details about the Property Animator, take a look at [iOS 10 Animations demo](https://github.com/handsomecode/iOS10-animations-demo).

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

This worked well for me. I wanted to animate a label with a continues fade in / fade out. I placed the label inside the "cardHeaderView".

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardHeaderView: UIView!
```

Place this inside the "viewDidAppear". I went with a delay of zero so the animation would start right away.

```
fadeViewInThenOut(view: cardHeaderView, delay: 0)
```

Here is the function.

```
func fadeViewInThenOut(view : UIView, delay: TimeInterval) {

    let animationDuration = 1.5

    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: delay, options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse, UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat], animations: {
        view.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for a 2 second fade in, 2 second pause, 2 second fade out and repeat.

```swift
func startAnimation() {
     UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 6.0,
                                    delay: 0,
                                    options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .calculationModeLinear]) {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.165) { [weak self] in
            self?.view1.alpha = 0.0
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.165, relativeDuration: 0.165) { [weak self] in
            self?.view2.alpha = 1.0
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.66, relativeDuration: 0.165) { [weak self] in
            self?.view2.alpha = 0.0
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.825, relativeDuration: 0.165) { [weak self] in
            self?.view1.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```